# Rails Gem to Activate selected users on sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, rubygems, omniauth

I am working on a web portal and want to implement a signup mechanism , where a people with certain qualities would be activated to use the portal.

Here are 2 things I am looking for :

```
    1]
    As a simple example, anyone who went to stanford and berkley could use it (So email should have @stanford.edu OR Linkedin Profile should indicated similar etc) . This could be extended to other similar constraints. 

    For now, its fine if I have to manually visit LinkedIn page, or exchange some emails before the approval is done.  

    2] 
    Some users with a pre-generated code are allowed to signup irrespective of above constraints. Eg a Gift card that has a membership pre-approved. 

3] 
This is not important , but there could be some pages/routes that could be available to everyone without approval.
```

I am looking for a Gem to perform this task or any suggestions of how this could be implemented quickly and elegantly. Its fine if the solution just scales to say 10K users.

Thanks!

P.S:
Currently I am using Devise and Omni-auth to support authentication, so would be even better if those could be supported in the new solution

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Devise Wiki Page on Approvals](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in) for the initial set-up of an approval process, which will notify you (or whomever you choose) when new users have registered via an `AdminMailer` mailer.

Then, by making use of a `before_create` callback, you can check your custom validations ie:

```
def approved_via_linked_in?
    # perform logic here...
end
```

And, you can set a condition on the email message which would send from your `AdminMailer` to only send if the user has not been approved yet by your custom validations.